# Converting Existing App To New Material Design

Tags: android, layout, material-design, android-appcompat

i am trying to change the design of an existing app with a new design given by client, the app is none but Q-Municate from Quickblox, the exisitng design is old and using ActionBar, i want to replace everything with the latest Material Design, Adding AppCompact v7 Lib 23,causes affect and errors to some other libraries , so i am using AppCompact v7 19
A Good tutorial or step by step guideline would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

I am pasting my styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeStyle">@style/MyActionMode</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="android:Widget.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/action_bar_background_color</item>
        <item name="android:displayOptions">showTitle</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
        <item name="android:indeterminateProgressStyle">@style/IndeterminateProgressStyle</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar title body -->
    <style name="MyActionBarTitleText" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionMode">
        <item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/badge_action_mode</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/badge_action_mode</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionModeTitleText</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionModeTitleText" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="baseToggleBtn">

        <item name="android:textOff"></item>
        <item name="android:textOn"></item>
    </style>

    <!-- EmojiTabs styles -->
    <style name="EmojiTabImageButton" parent="android:Widget.ImageButton">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_emoji_selector</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dip</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Avatars ImageView style -->
    <style name="AvatarImageView">
        <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/image_view_big_avatar_layout_width</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/image_view_big_avatar_layout_height</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center|top</item>
        <item name="android:scaleType">centerCrop</item>
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/placeholder_user</item>
    </style>

    <style name="IndeterminateProgressStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar">
        <item name="android:minHeight">24dp</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">24dp</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">32dp</item>
        <item name="android:maxWidth">32dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DoneCancelBar">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/action_bar_height</item>
        <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:divider">@drawable/ic_action_divider</item>
        <item name="android:showDividers" tools:ignore="NewApi">middle</item>
        <item name="android:dividerPadding" tools:ignore="NewApi">12dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/action_button_bar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionButton">
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_selectable_background</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionButtonText">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">20dp</item>
        <!-- Offsets left drawable -->
        <item name="android:drawablePadding">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/action_button_text</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">13sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionButtonText.Done">
        <item name="android:drawableLeft">@drawable/ic_action_done</item>
        <item name="android:text">@string/dlg_done</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionButtonText.Cancel">
        <item name="android:drawableLeft">@drawable/ic_action_cancel</item>
        <item name="android:text">@string/dlg_cancel</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the previsualicer of the mobile phone, you can choose the theme here and choose material (dark or light)

Comment: i think you haven't gone through the question

Comment: yes yes I know what you say, you can do it like I say, but are more options